# Strange behavior synchronizing android

Tags: android-studio, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I have a app synchonizing datas with Web Service. The first time app is intalled all work fine but when I run the app again, the two tables are updated with data from a single table. Specifically with the last one running in the code.

SyncAdapter start in onCreate method of MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    SyncAdapter.inicializarSyncAdapter(this);
    SyncAdapter.sincronizarAhora(this, false);

}
```

onPerformSync method from SyncAdapter:

```
    @Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account,
                          Bundle extras,
                          String authority,
                          ContentProviderClient provider,
                          final SyncResult syncResult) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onPerformSync()...");

    boolean soloSubida = extras.getBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_UPLOAD, false);

    if (!soloSubida) {
        realizarSincronizacionLocal(syncResult);
    } else {
        realizarSincronizacionRemota();
    }
}
```

I do not understand why this happens. Can somebody help me?

Comment: which api you are running?

Comment: Im running the app in  Nexus 5 API 24. 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asir.javi.infotest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }